# mysql Like issue

Tags: mysql, opencart

I think I found a bug in `opencart` so in the featured module there is an autocomplete box which suggests products but it seems to skip a whole bunch. After examining the code it looks like it all boils down to this database query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM calcproduct p 
LEFT JOIN calcproduct_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
WHERE pd.language_id = '1' AND LCASE(pd.name) LIKE 'ti %' 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY pd.name ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

When I run the query manually for example I have two products:

```
TI | 83 | Brand New
TI | 83 | Like New
```

It only finds one of them and it's doing this for other products as well. Does anyone have any clue why this happens?

It has to be the like part of the query i took out the group by and order by and even the first where clause. I tried changing the column from `utf_8` to `latin_1`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your query looks for whitespace after `ti`.  Does one of those rows not have that whitespace?  `LIKE 'ti %' ` should be `LIKE 'ti%' ` ??

Comment: If you removed the "group by" clause, my next suggestion would be to ensure both the calcproduct record and the calcproduct_description record exists. Even though you're using a left join, your "where" clause includes references to the value of "pd.name" and pd.language so a record from each table must be present.

Comment: if i do Like'%' then they both show up so i don't think it's because of that it's something specificly related to the like clause i believe

Comment: Please show some schema, and column names for your example results, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I think Michael is on the money, and `TI` is not followed by a space but another whitespace character. Also shown by the fact that in the second example it sorts _after_ some `TI 84`'s although there is an `ORDER BY pd.name`.  I'd be interested in the `HEX()` output of both names...

Comment: I figure it out there was a space in front of those product name that weren't showing up

Comment: This should be on Opencart forums. Not SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out there was a space in front of those product name that weren't showing up

Answer (score 2):

If that `83` is the p.product_id field, then you would only ever get one of those two rows. Any fields which are grouped, where two or more rows have the same value, will collapse down into a single row.

Comment: its' not they each have unique product id's